# Office ContentControls List Inaccurate

Tags: javascript, office-addins

I can do this a couple of ways, but let's stick to the AddIn itself.  If I create a ContentControl:

```
Word.run((context) => {
    let control = context.document.getSelection().insertContentControl();
    control.tag = 'example';
    control.insertOoxml('<xml here>');
    context.sync();
});
```

Then later (with proper async handling of course) I delete the control:

```
Word.run((context) => {
    let contentControls = context.document.contentControls;
    context.load(contentControls, 'tag');
    context.sync().then(() => {
        for (let c = 0; c < contentControls.items.length; ++c) {
            if (contentControls.items[c].tag === 'example') {
                contentControls.items[c].delete(false); // delete the contentControl with the matching tag
            }
        }
        context.sync()
    });
});
```

Then I check the list of content controls for that control I just deleted:

```
Word.run((context) => {
    let contentControls = context.document.contentControls;
    context.load(contentControls, 'tag');
    context.sync().then(() => {
        for (var i = 0; i < contentControls.items.length; ++i) {
            if (contentControls.items[c].tag === 'example') {
                // this tag list still includes the deleted content control until I close and reopen the document
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The tags still show the deleted content control.  I have to close and reopen the document for the context to refresh.  Am I missing a step for proper syncing with the current state of the document?  Is `context.sync()` not enough?

NOTE: `delete()` does work: the content disappears from the document as expected.  It's just still in the list of controls when I search the document.

---

Further research has determined the cause of this.

When TrackChanges is on, the ContentControls in the document are not ACTUALLY deleted.  This still feels like a word bug, but you can check for the deleted flag on the contentcontrol (not sure offhand if that's really possible because it might be at some arbitrary level of the ancestry), manage your deletions manually (as we're doing), or turn off track changes to resolve this issue.

All that said, I am going to leave this up as a question in case someone has a better resultion.

Comment: well, with no bounty answer either, I'll just go with my temp workaround: tracking deleted content controls manually

Answer (score 0):

Try to check list after you sync your context - in `.then` callback:

```
Word.run((context) => {
    let contentControls = context.document.contentControls;
    context.load(contentControls, 'tag');
    context.sync().then(() => {
        for (let c = 0; c < contentControls.items.length; ++c) {
            if (contentControls.items[c].tag === 'example') {
                contentControls.items[c].delete(false); // delete the contentControl with the matching tag
            }
        }
        context.sync().then(()=> {
            //your updated list
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: that's what I'm doing.  In this case, I'm trying to load the contentControls from scratch on a later call and the deleted one is still in the list (in spite of syncing)